# Ldap create user with custom attributes and objectclasses

Tags: attributes, ldap

I am trying to add custom attributes and object classes in my LDAP(ODSEE) but having issues.

Initially, I had issues with adding the custom attributes and classes, but was finally it worked. My custom definitions look like below(got the test code from one of the sites for testing)

```
dn: cn=schema
changetype: modify
add: attributeTypes
attributeTypes: ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.4203.666.1.90 
 NAME ( 'personStatus' ) 
 DESC 'person Status' 
 SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15 
 MULTI-VALUE )

dn: cn=schema
changetype: modify
add: objectClasses
objectClasses: ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.4203.666.1.100
  NAME 'YoLinuxPerson'
  DESC 'Yo Linux Person’
  SUP inetOrgPerson 
  AUXILIARY 
  MAY personStatus )
```

My user ldif is as below

```
dn: uid=acc, ou=People, dc=example,dc=com
**objectClass: YoLinuxPerson*******************Custom
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: person
objectClass: top
cn: aaaaa Vaughan
sn: Vaughan
facsimileTelephoneNumber: +1 408 555 3372
givenName: Kirsten
l: Sunnyvale
mail: aaaaa@example.com
ou: Human Resources
ou: People
roomNumber: 2871
telephoneNumber: +1 408 555 5625
uid: aaaaa
**personStatus: abcdefghij**********************Custom
userPassword:: e1NTSEF9WhgljhlWxzZUdDUVVFUW05OTg1bmJSUkpoNHdYUVgrZkE9P
```

I tried multiple ways but everything fails. If I remove the "personStatus: abcdefghij" the ldapadd command works, but if I have it there, it fails saying

```
[config]$ ldapadd -h  -p -D "cn=" -w -f User.ldif 
adding new entry uid=acc, ou=People, dc=example,dc=com
ldap_add: Object class violation
```

I also did a ldap search

```
- ldapsearch -D -w -h  -p -b "cn=schema" -s base 'objectclass=*'
```

and it displayed all the results including the custom attribute (which I am having issues with), but i could not see the custom objectClass(which I can add to the user).

I tried with Apache Studio also, it fails with the same message. I am not sure what I am missing. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's a problem with the objectClass definition :
Either it extends inetOrgPerson, and thus it's a STRUCTURAL objectClass,
Or it is AUXILIARY and doesn't need to extend inetOrgPerson.

But your issue may be that you need to restart DSEE to be able to set the entry with the new objectClass and attribute (I vaguely remember an issue in that domain, but it's been more than 5 years since I last played with DSEE).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I agree, I was just testing to create custom attributes. Actually the schema will not have any user details at all. Anyway the main issue was a space in between the entries. I updated the space and now it works fine. Thanks.